# Connexion to a distant Hadoop cluster (CDH4) via java

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-pig, cloudera

I have a distant Hadoop cluster of machines (Cloudera CDH4). And I'm trying to run a pig script from my computer. Here is my JAVA code to do so:

```
import org.apache.pig.ExecType;
import org.apache.pig.PigServer;
import org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

public class TestPig {

public static void main(String args[]){

    PigServer pigServer;
    try {

        /** On définit les propriétés */
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("fs.default.name", "hdfs://master.node.ip.adress:8020");
        props.setProperty("mapred.job.tracker", "master.node.ip.adress:8021");





        System.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl");

        /** mapreduce mode */
        pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE, props);

        /** pig script's path */
        pigServer.registerScript("/user/admin/data/script.pig");

        /** printing the pig script's output */
        Iterator<Tuple> results = pigServer.openIterator("A");
        while(results.hasNext())
            System.out.println(results.next().toDelimitedString("\t"));


    } 
    catch (ExecException e) {   e.printStackTrace(); } 
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

}
}
```

When I launch this program, I have the following error:

> 13/07/19 10:44:02 INFO executionengine.HExecutionEngine: Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://master.node.ip.adress:8020
>   13/07/19 10:44:23 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master.cs236cloud.internal/master.node.ip.adress:8020. Already tried 0 time(s); maxRetries=45
>
> ...
>
> 13/07/19 10:59:27 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master.cs236cloud.internal/master.node.ip.adress:8020. Already tried 43 time(s); maxRetries=45
>   13/07/19 10:59:48 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master.cs236cloud.internal/master.node.ip.adress:8020. Already tried 44 time(s); maxRetries=45
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create DataStorage
>       at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.init(HDataStorage.java:75)
>       at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.(HDataStorage.java:58)
>       at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.init(HExecutionEngine.java:204)
>       at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.init(HExecutionEngine.java:117)
>       at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.connect(PigContext.java:240)
>       at org.apache.pig.PigServer.(PigServer.java:213)
>       at org.apache.pig.PigServer.(PigServer.java:198)
>       at org.apache.pig.PigServer.(PigServer.java:194)
>       at TestPig.main(TestPig.java:42)
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Call to master.cs236cloud.internal/master.node.ip.adress:8020 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=master.cs236cloud.internal/master.node.ip.adress:8020]
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1140)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1112)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
>       at $Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
>       at $Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.checkVersion(RPC.java:422)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createNamenode(DFSClient.java:183)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:281)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:245)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:100)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1437)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1455)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:123)
>       at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.init(HDataStorage.java:72)
>       ... 8 more
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=master.cs236cloud.internal/master.node.ip.adress:8020]
>       at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:213)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:511)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:481)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:453)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:579)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2100(Client.java:202)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1243)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1087)
>       ... 28 more

I'm sure that the master is listening at the 8020 port. Indeed, when I launch this command:

> netstat -an | grep 8020

I've got this result:

> tcp        0      0 master.local.ip.adress:8020              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN

I also want to give you my core-site.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Autogenerated by Cloudera CM on 2013-07-12T10:43:15.666Z-->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://Master.cs236cloud.internal:8020</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.trash.interval</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>io.file.buffer.size</name>
    <value>65536</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
       <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DeflateCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Lz4Codec</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
    <value>simple</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.rpc.protection</name>
    <value>authentication</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.security.auth_to_local</name>
    <value>DEFAULT</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Here is the result of jps command on my master machine:

```
3250 DataNode
4468 Main
2776 HeadlampServer
2541 RunJar
5496 Jps
4467 EventCatcherService
2502 QuorumPeerMain
2650 JobTracker
3082 RunJar
2597 HRegionServer
2594 TaskTracker
2629 HMaster
2520
3003 SecondaryNameNode
4553 Main
3414 Bootstrap
2549 AlertPublisher
3172 NameNode
2127 Main
4583 Main
3350 Bootstrap
```

I searched on the internet for solutions, but i didn't found anything that works.

Dou you have an Idea on how to solve the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you solved it?